# Adding a function to /etc/profile causes gnome to restart after login

Tags: bash, authentication, profile, gnome

I recently added the following bash function definition to my /etc/profile in Ubuntu 11.04 (it's a function to shortcut a CD command to a specific development directory):

```
################## JMOZTELEPORT BEGIN ##################

function JMozTeleport() {
  version=0.4.58
  pathtopythonpackages=`python -c "from site import getsitepackages; print getsitepackages()[0]"`
  pathtopythonteleport="$pathtopythonpackages/JMozTools-$version-py2.7.egg/JMozTools/JMozTeleport.py"

  # $1 is the command to run
  isversion=0
  ishelp=0
  if [[ "$1" == "-v"  || "$1" == "--version" ]]
  then
    isversion=1;
  fi
  if [[ "$1" == "-h"  || "$1" == "--help" ]]
  then
    ishelp=1;
  fi
  if [ -z $1 ]
  then
    python "$pathtopythonteleport" "-h"
  elif [ $1 == "version" ]
  then
    echo $version
  elif [ $isversion == 1 -o $ishelp == 1 ]
  then
    python "$pathtopythonteleport" "$@"
  else
    cd $(python "$pathtopythonteleport" "$@")
  fi
}
################### JMOZTELEPORT END ###################
```

Once I do this, though, (which works fine if I source /etc/profile from a terminal shell), I am unable to login to Gnome. It logs in ok, but then it immediately closes Gnome and brings me back to the login screen. If I remove this stuff from my /etc/profile, it again allows me to login fine.

I'm confused as to what is causing this to make gnome restart. Any ideas as to where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/profile` is sourced by `/bin/sh`, something that probably happens during Gnome startup.  It's probably choking on the `[[ ... ]]` syntax, which is bash-specific.  (`/bin/sh` may or may not be a symlink to `/bin/bash`, depending on the system).

Since your function appears to be bash-specific, you might consider putting it in `/etc/bash.bashrc` rather than `/etc/profile`, or perhaps even `$HOME/.bashrc`.  (Do you need it in non-interactive shells?)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up placing it in /etc/bashrc.

Answer (score 2):

You put it under debug and see what is causing it to restart. Use, the `set -x` command to enable debug mode. Similarly the `set +x` command disables it.

Putting `set -x` at the top of your `/etc/profile` should cause debug information to be printed out.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, and I did use this, but the other answer really was the problem, so I accepted that one instead. I did appreciate the information, though... this will definitely be helpful in the future.

Comment: Sure, no problem. All the best and have a great new year! :)